# Xamarin UWP Set PasswordBox Placeholder Color

Tags: xamarin, uwp, passwordbox

I have a Xamarin.Forms Shared project with a login page. For UWP I would like to use the password reveal functionality, which is why I need the PasswordBox Control. I would like to set the placeholdertext color for the PasswordBox control in UWP. The problem is Xamarin does not have a PasswordBoxRenderer and the PasswordBox control does not have a property to edit the placeholder foreground color.

I haven't been able to find an updated/Xamarin solution. Any help or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to override default brush in PasswordBox resource, like this:

```
<PasswordBox PlaceholderText="PASSWORD">
            <PasswordBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused" Color="Red"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForeground" Color="Red"/>
            </PasswordBox.Resources>
        </PasswordBox>
```

You also may override: TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver, TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled

Add new UserControl to you project then change it to:

```
<PasswordBox
    x:Class="App3.CustomPasswordBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="200" Height="50" PlaceholderText="PlaceHolder">
    <PasswordBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForeground" Color="Red"/>
    </PasswordBox.Resources>
</PasswordBox>
```

Remove CustomPasswordBox.xaml.cs.

Create new Renderer:

```
public class PasswordRenderer : ViewRenderer<Entry, CustomPasswordBox>
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Ok, now where exactly do I place your xaml code and how can I use it or reference it in my shared project Xaml(or code behind)?

Comment: In UWP project create new control with XAML, change it type to PasswordBox in xaml and code behind. And add the code in answer

Comment: Ok, i'm not sure I understand how you want me to do that. Do I make a new UserControl in the UWP Project with the passwordbox defined in xaml and then Reference it from my Shared Project? Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Update my answer

Comment: Trying this , I'm getting the error: the type custompasswordbox can not be used as type parameter TNativeElement..... There is no implicit reference conversion from custompasswordbox to windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.  A new renderer does seem the way to go.

Comment: Buidling the above code I get: "cannot derive from sealed class PasswordBox".  So I assume I have to wrap it inside a Grid or something else. Only problem is, how do you acces the passwordbox.password property if it's inside a parent element.

Comment: You have no parent for CustomPasswordBox in my answer, it's representation PasswordBox in XAML. Xaml.cs you need to remove. I will provide example at github in few minutes